# PHP If Statement conditions not working

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if($InboundTextBody === 'Help' OR 'help'){
   echo 'help';
} 
elseif($InboundTextBody === 'Reset'){
      echo 'send reset message';
}
elseif($InboundTextBody === 'Start'){
       echo 'send start message';
}

if($InboundTextBody === 'Help' || 'help'){
   echo 'help';
}
```

If my $InboundTextBody has the word Help. It will echo Help. If the $InboundTextBody has the word Reset it still echo help. it never echo reset. 
I need the or in my statement just in case the $InboundTextBody text has up case or lower case text

Comment: Take care about the operator precedence!

Comment: Let me put some parenthesis to empathize that for you: `if(($InboundTextBody === 'Help') OR ('help')){`

Comment: `OR 'help'` is being compared to nothing. You need another `$InboundTextBody ===`. or you could do `in_array($InboundTextBody, array('help', 'Help'))`, or just convert the case of that to all lowercase, or title case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for your `IF` is

```
if($InboundTextBody === 'Help' OR $InboundTextBody === 'help'){
```

Or you could convert all to lowercase and do

```
if(strtolower($InboundTextBody) === 'help'){
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use function strtolower for avoiding the check on UPPER and LOWER case.

```
if(strtolower($InboundTextBody) === 'help')
```

By the way, the correct `IF` form is:

```
if($InboundTextBody === 'Help' OR $InboundTextBody === 'help')
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it would be to use the built-in case-insensitive string comparison function, `strcasecmp`. ([php.net doc here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php))

```
if (strcasecmp($InboundTextBody, 'help') == 0) {
    echo 'help';
} elseif (strcasecmp($InBoundTextBody, 'reset') == 0) {
    echo 'reset';
}
```

Note that the result of `strcasecmp` will be `0` if they ARE the same.

Please note that in your solution, `if($InboundTextBody === 'Help' || 'help')` does not check what if `$InboundTextBody` is either. It only checks if it is 'Help', but after the `||`, you have the equivalent of: `if ('help')` which will always return true, since `'help'` is not falsy (e.g. not a 0 or null).