# PHP if Statement numbers as strings

Tags: php, if-statement

`$InboundTextBody ="1"`. When the code runs it does not set `$TypeOptions = good` however if I spell the word one like `$InboundTextBody ="one"` then I get `great`. How can I get the if statement to recognize a input `1` as a string

```
if ($InboundTextBody === "1") {
    $TypeOptions = "good";
}
elseif ($InboundTextBody === "One") {
    $TypeOptions = "great";
}
elseif ($InboundTextBody === "3") {
    $TypeOptions = "best";
}
```

Comment: Your input is **already** a string. You wrap the number in quotation marks in order for it to be parsed as a string. You can check this with [**gettype($InboundTextBody)**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php).

Comment: `1` as a variable type string is still the single character `1`, not `One`. You could make an array with all the variations of one then use `in_array`.

Comment: `$InboundTextBody = "1"; if ($InboundTextBody === "1") { echo "HERE\n"; }` outputs "HERE". So the code you shared works fine (`$InboundTextBody = "1"` at the top and then the larger code block). Please share *actual code you're running* that reproduces the problem.

Comment: If they get `great` (which is how I read the question) then `$InboundTextBody` must be `One`.

Comment: We have **no way** to know what `$InboundTextBody` is and where that is, **you have that**.

Comment: This seems to be a continuation of your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44739757/1415724

Comment: You have answers; deal with those, I'm out/will pass on this one, fearing a rabbit hole.

Comment: It's possible that whatever is setting the variable `$InboundTextBody` to the value `1` is actually setting it to an int and not a string. Try echoing the type of `$InboundTextBody` when you set it to `1` to see whether it is an int or a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$InboundTextBody = "1";

if ($InboundTextBody === "1"){
    $TypeOptions = "good";
}
elseif ($InboundTextBody === "One"){
    $TypeOptions = "great";
}
elseif ($InboundTextBody === "3"){
    $TypeOptions = "best";
}

echo $TypeOptions;
```

output:

```
[Running] php "test.php"
good
```

Aside from camel casing, there is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use casting operators to do that.

Put that code before your conditionals:

```
$InboundTextBody = (string)$InboundTextBody;
```

Then:

```
if ($InboundTextBody === "1"){
   $TypeOptions = "good";
}
elseif ($InboundTextBody === "One"){
   $TypeOptions = "great";
}
elseif ($InboundTextBody === "3"){
    $TypeOptions = "best";
}
```

Will returns what you want.

Comment: Very start of the question: `$InboundTextBody ="1"`

Answer (score -1):

When you use `===` PHP is evaluating your `"1"` as a string. If `$InboundTextBody` equals `1`(number) then it won't work as you want. You can try to use `==` instead of `===` to make it work(since `===` is a strict comparision operator, while `==` is not). 
Here how it will work:

```
if ($InboundTextBody == "1"){
    $TypeOptions = "good";
}
elseif ($InboundTextBody == "One"){
    $TypeOptions = "great";
}
elseif ($InboundTextBody == "3"){
    $TypeOptions = "best";
}
```

Or if you are sure, that every possible `$InboundTextBody` should be string, then you should add one more line before the `if` statement:

```
$InboundTextBody = strval($InboundTextBody);
if ($InboundTextBody === "1"){
    $TypeOptions = "good";
}
elseif ($InboundTextBody === "One"){
    $TypeOptions = "great";
}
elseif ($InboundTextBody === "3"){
    $TypeOptions = "best";
}
```

Comment: Very start of the question: `$InboundTextBody ="1"`

Comment: @smarx if it was actually `$InboundTextBody ="1"` then it would work without problems.

Comment: Agreed. (I commented as much on the question.) So why don't we wait to see what the actual code is?